# ExtJs Dynamic Store Failed call Handle

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, store

I have a clasic store

```
Ext.define('xxx.store.Search', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'xxx.model.Search',
    requires: ['xxx.data.xxxx'],
    proxy:
            {
                type: 'xxxxx',
                digSearchUrl: {
                    initRequest: 'ajax/xxx/xxx/xx',
                    pollRequest: 'ajax/xxxx/xxxx/xxxxxx'
                }
            },
    autoLoad: false,
    defaultSortDirection: 'DESC'
});
```

Now i usually do a store load like this:

```
   this.getStore('Search').load({
        digSearchCfg: {
            xxx: sid,
            xxx: xxxx
        }
    });
```

I know i could use the standard approch like in here: 
[Attempting to load Ext store with JSON data from AJAX request returns error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907860/attempting-to-load-ext-store-with-json-data-from-ajax-request-returns-error)
But i would rather define the error handler in the store it self. is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to catch and handle the Ajax request exceptions yourself just add a Exception listener to the Ajax proxy, like so:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
        fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'data2.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'characters'
            },
            listeners: {
                exception: function(proxy, response, operation, eOpts ) {
                    console.log("EXCEPTION CAUGHT!");
                }
            }
        },
        listeners: {
            load: function() {
                console.log(this);
            }
        }
    });
```

You can see a demo fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/grg). data1.json will work and will log the store object to console. data2.json will log 'EXCEPTION CAUGHT!' to the console.

Here is the documentation for the [Ajax proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-event-exception) for reference.